# Create a new row if a value in a row in dataframe endswith ,

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having dataframe like this

| Text | Label |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | name |
| Smith, | name |
| Other | 0 |

I want to loop through every row in the dataframe to check if any values in the "Text" column ends with "," I will remove that comma and move it to a new row with the label 0 like this. How can I do that?

What I expected:

| Text | Label |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | name |
| Smith | name |
| , | 0 |
| Other | 0 |

Thanks

Comment: Do you have only , in the end or will there be any other punctuations as well?

Comment: Yes, I want to check only "," in the end

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Split the text by comma or semi-colon, Explode the text column and replace values based on condition

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.split('(?=[,;]$)')
df = df.explode('Text')
df.loc[df.Text.str.contains('[,;]$'), 'Label'] = 0
```

Comment: @vjugieje if you want to ignore the index pass `ignore_index=True` to explode, or reset it afterwards by adding the line `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: I think it is best to use the regex pattern`str.split(',$')` to ensure that the string is only split in case it ends with `,` as OP wants. The solution works for the example given, but in case there are `Text` values like `"Don't, Split, This"` it fails

Comment: I got it, i just detected there's another case when it ends with ';', how could I handle this? thanks @Rodalm

Comment: @Vishnudev i just detected there's another case when it ends with ';', how could I handle this? Thank you

Comment: @vjugieje try `str.strip(',|;$')`

Comment: @Rodalm any changes here? df.loc[df.Text == ''] = [',', 0] Because if not it will replace the ; by ,

Comment: @vjugieje Sorry for the mistake in the last statement. Please check now. It works.

Comment: @Vishnudev hi, got update that I am facing this error ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.

Comment: @Rodalm I got this error when running the above code, any idea? ValueError: split() requires a non-empty pattern match

Comment: It did not get a match. Works only if the pattern is matched at least once.